# MacOS/iTerm2/fish arrow keys stops working after terminating a process with ctrl+c

Tags: terminal, macos, fish, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 on my mac pro, and using fish as my shell. Every time I have a process running and I break it by pressing ctrl+c, the arrow keys stops working after and starts emitting ^[[A etc.

Attached a screenshot to my iTerm2 preferences > Profiles [Default] > Terminal

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program has switched to *application mode* for the cursor-keys (and does not cleanup when interrupted).  You can manually switch back using this command:

```
tput rmkx
```

Some terminal emulators have a setting in a dialog which lets you do the same thing.